# How to cast string to date?

Tags: sql, casting, db2

Date `1190502` indicates `02/05/2019` :

| DT |
| --- |
| 1190502 |
| 1190503 |
| 1190504 |
| 1190505 |
| 1190506 |
| 1190507 |

I want to cast this to a date format. Following query fails:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(DT,6,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(DT,4,2)+'/'+'20'+SUBSTRING(DT,2,2) AS DATE) FROM table
```

Comment: What is the significance of the leading digit (1, in this case) ?

Comment: I'm using dbeaver. Yes, '1' is unnecessary here. I need to get rid of that digit as well

Comment: [SQL0402] + use not valid.....this error pops

Comment: your query works [sql-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5a2b54/1)

Answer (score 1):

> SQL0402 SQLCODE -402
>
> SQLSTATE 42819 Explanation: &1 use not valid.

This is a DB/2 Error Message, so try to use concat:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(DT,6,2) concat '/' concat SUBSTRING(DT,4,2) concat '/20' concat SUBSTRING(DT,2,2) as DATE) 
FROM table
```

[db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=b0f0c72229d890865333d95650259e5e)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `TRY_CONVERT` here if your version of SQL Server support it:

```sql
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING('1190502', 2, 6));  -- 2019-05-02 00:00:00.000
```

Or, you could use the older `CONVERT` function, with the correct format mask:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING('1190502', 2, 6), 112);  -- 2019-05-02 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT C, DATE(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(C, 2), 'YYMMDD')) D
FROM
(
VALUES
  '1190502'
, '1190503'
, '1190504'
, '1190505'
, '1190506'
, '1190507'
) T (C);

|C      |D         |
|-------|----------|
|1190502|2019-05-02|
|1190503|2019-05-03|
|1190504|2019-05-04|
|1190505|2019-05-05|
|1190506|2019-05-06|
|1190507|2019-05-07|
```

Comment: But actually, you shouldn't just "get rid" of the 1-st character. It seems that the 1-st char is for century. 0 - 20-th, 1 - 21-th, etc. So, the correct expression should be `DATE(TO_DATE('00'||SUBSTR(C, 2), 'YYYYMMDD')  + (1900 + INT(SUBSTR(C, 1, 1)) * 100) YEARS)`